# this.props.function is not a function - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goals are to make a redirection with a **BACK** button, but until now no success.
When i'm trying to pass a function from child to parent it return me :

> **_this.props.callHomeFunction is not a function**

**Parent.js**

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            okRedirect: false,
        }

        this.consoleToHome = this.consoleToHome.bind(this)
    }

    consoleToHome = (test) => {
        // this.setState({ okRedirect: true });
        console.log('go to home');
        console.log(test);
    }
render(){
  return(
    <Router>
      <Select callHomeFunction={this.consoleToHome} />
```

**Child.js**

```
class BackButton extends Component {

  changePage = () => {
    const test = 'test';
    console.log('click on home');
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.callHomeFunction(test);
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div className='back_buttons'>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button className='back_buttons back_button'
              onClick={this.changePage}
            >
```

Comment: Child cannot send props to parent.

Comment: You don't have to bind `consoleToHome` on `this` as you are using an arrow function. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: You're passing a function to Select, not BackButton

Comment: @estus if i pass `onClick={this.changePage()}` the result is the same , but this time doesnt show the next page after the Home

Comment: it should be `onClick={this.changePage}`, not `onClick={this.changePage()}`. If the problem persists, consider updating the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that reflects your current attempt.

Comment: @estus normally in my code is `onClick={this.changePage}` im not passing a function in my `onClick` . If you check the example above you will see that my code is like the suggestion that you have recommended .

Comment: Yes. But you passed it to Select and not BackButton. If you do one thing the right way and another thing the wrong way, the result is wrong any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding's of the components are correct as far I see the code,

Please check the Component names, You child Component name is BackButton but when you are including you are using <**select>**.

If the above didn't solve the problem please post your error

Comment: yep i found my mistake . Cheers mate !

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor with super function in Child.js

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: nope , i had a constructor before , but the result is the same

Comment: lets try to add bind method in onclick method like this
```onClick={this.changePage.bind()}```

and also add constructor with super
```constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}```

Comment: Unfortunately the result stays the same